# Segmentation fault after free variables which are used return in function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, free, mtrace

I need the last 2 column in ipv6 address. (2001:1234:asdd:xeed:212:4b00:61) --> (4b0061) also i need to know how to free this return of ipv6_parser function.

it is given "Segmentation fault"  when i am trying to free result.

```
char* ipv6_parser(char* str){
    char *ret = malloc(sizeof(str));

  ret = str;
  ret = strtok(ret,":");
  int i ;
  for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        ret = strtok(NULL, ":");
  }
  char *last = strtok(NULL, ":");
  sprintf(ret,"%s%s",ret,last);

  return ret;
}

int main(){
  mtrace();

    char *str=strdup("2001:1234:asdd:xeed:212:4b00:61");
    char* result    = ipv6_parser(str); 
    printf("\nResult - %s\n",result);
  free(result);
  free(str);
return(0);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(str)` and `strlen(str)` are very different

Comment: It's pointless to allocate memory for `ret` if you're just going to overwrite the pointer to that memory in the very next statement.  Perhaps you were looking for `strdup()`?

Comment: Use a memory debugger such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to help you find problems.

Comment: Whether you obtain the memory via `malloc()` or via `strdup()`, to free it you must pass a pointer to the *start* of the block.  You are losing that pointer by overwriting it with the return value of `strtok()`.

Comment: You get the seg fault because your program doesn't make any sense. Read up about arrays and strings, and the `strcpy` function.

Comment: Someone please link me a canonical duplicate for "how do you copy strings in C"? I'm certain there is one but I can't find it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, that comments is helping to improve myself about c programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `ret = str;` is not copying the string but assigning the input pointer itself to `ret` and causing memory leak.
- You cannot use `sizeof(str)` to determine the length of string.
- `sprintf(ret,"%s%s",ret,last);` invokes *undefined behavior* by copying between overwrapped objects.

Try this:

```
char* ipv6_parser(const char* str){
  char *ret = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
  if (ret == NULL){
    perror("malloc ret");
    return NULL;
  }
  char *ret_buffer = ret; /* store where the buffer is to free it after using */

  strcpy(ret,str);
  ret = strtok(ret,":");
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<5;i++){
    ret = strtok(NULL, ":");
  }
  char *last = strtok(NULL, ":");
  char *final_ret = malloc(strlen(ret) + strlen(last) + 1);
  if (final_ret == NULL){
    perror("malloc final_ret");
    free(ret_buffer);
    return NULL;
  }
  sprintf(final_ret,"%s%s",ret,last);
  free(ret_buffer);

  return final_ret;
}
```

Comment: Given that the OP is already using `strdup()`, you can cut the `malloc(strlen + 1); strcpy()` raindance.

Comment: Thank you for your help. it is working with this codes. I understand what i need to do when i encountered to that cases.